# How can I automatically stop an EC2 Instance once network bandwidth exceeds a predefined limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently experimenting with AWS Free Tier. I understand that, for AWS Data Transfer, the following limit applies:

$0 for 100GB of data transfer out to the internet, aggregated globally, each month.

I am using a single EC2 instance in one AWS Region. I wonder if I can configure the instance to automatically stop, once the data transfer out to the internet hits the 100GB limit?

Comment: Yes, you can create a cloudwatch alarm for for NetworkOut netric for your instance. Select `stop this instance ` from `EC2 action` once the threshold is reached.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup [AWS CloudWatch Alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html) based on [NetworkOut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html#ec2-cloudwatch-metrics) metric for your instance. When triggered, the alarm would [stop the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html).

Comment: isn't it Networkout..?

Comment: @Riz Yes. Thanks for spotting that. answer corrected.

Comment: Thanks. But during the alarm creation, I need to specify the period used to calculate the SUM(NetworkOut), which to me seems relative to the current timestamp (previous 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week, ...etc)

I can't find a way to aggregate the data over the current month (April 2022 for example), and fire the alert appropriately.

Comment: @Amr Yes, its moving average. If you don't want that, you have to develop your own, fully custom solution for monitoring your instances.

Answer (score 1):

Oookay.. So I figured out how to achieve this. The solution below takes into account the accumulative network bandwidth (Internet OUT) over a month period, as opposed to the moving average retrieved in the CloudWatch.

1. Create a new tag in your EC2 instance. In my case, I created a new tag name and assigned my custom value, to uniquely identify my instance (example: tag key "email-server", tag value "us-server"
2. Wait up to 24 hours (essential)
3. Activating User-Defined Cost Allocation Tags (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/activating-tags.html)
4. In the above step, you should find your new tag key. You need to activate it (Note: in case you create a new tag key, you really need to wait for up to 24 hours for the user-defined cost allocation tags list to update)
5. Once activated, you need to wait again for up to 24 hours
6. Go to AWS Budgets
7. Create a new Budget. In my case, I chose "Usage Budget"
8. In the "Usage Type Groups", select "EC2: Data Transfer - Internet (Out)"
9. Under "Budget Scope", select "Filter specific AWS cost dimensions"
10. Click "Add Filter", Dimension --> "Tag", Tag --> Choose your newly created tag, in my case "email-server". Finally in the Values filed, select the tag values you want to include in your budget, in my case "us-server".
11. Afterwards, you will optionally be able to add custom alerting (example: if 80% of the budget is consumed), and you can also define action items (example: shut down instance).

Comment: no matter how long i wait i don't see the cost tag when creating the budget